# Azure alerts for key vault certificates

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault, alerts

I am trying to set up alerts for key vault certificate expiration.  So I get an azure alert say when the cert is about to expire in X days.

Many thanks

Comment: Ok, so what is the issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Enable diagnostic settings on the Key Vault and save it to a log analytics workspace, then you can create a custom log alert rule, to trigger on the e.g. Microsoft.KeyVault.CertificateNearExpiry event.

Answer (score 2):

**To set up alerts for key vault certificate expiration, try below steps:**

> Azure Key vault provides mechanism to trigger events when the status of a secret stored in key vault has changed. Key Vault integration with Event Grid allows users to be notified when the status of secret stored in key vault has changed.

you can make use of `Microsoft.KeyVault.CertificateNearExpiry` Triggers when the currents version is about to expire (30 days) as mentioned in the expiry date of the Key vault record.

- To create event grid subscription**, **go to key vault** -> **Events -> get started -> logic apps****
- To configure the **Event Grid Trigger** select your **subscription** , your  Resource Type as  **Microsoft.KeyVault.vaults** and select your **key vault name** -> click **Save As**
- Along with logic apps  ***Event Grid System Topic*** is created
  automatically in the logic app triggered select event type as `Microsoft.KeyVault.CertificateNearExpiry`

To more in detail please **refer** this link :

https://azureintegrations.com/2021/03/20/monitoring-and-alerting-for-azure-key-vault/

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with email alerting you can use [Certificate Contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/about-certificates#certificate-contacts), a functionality specific to Key Vault.
First you need to provide the email addresses of notifications recipients here:

[image]

Notifications will be sent for each stored certificate that has its [Issuance Policy lifecycle attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-rotate-certificates#update-lifecycle-attributes-of-a-stored-certificate) set to *Email all contacts* (can be either the number of days to expiry or at percentage of a lifetime):

[image]

Note that it can be updated also for the existing certificates, despite the fact that the message at the top of this window says the opposite.

Setting this up will result in notifications being sent automatically:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if this applies to certificates that are *imported* into Azure Key Vault, not just those that are created there?